# can anyone help me and write the program of this equation: x=n mod y, in assembly lsnguage

Tags: assembly, x86

How can i solve this problem in assembly language: using only SUB, MOV, AND instructions, show how to calculate `x = n mod y`, assuming that you are given the values of n and y. n is any 16-bit unsigned integer, and y is power of 2.

Comment: My wild guess is that this is homework, and for homework related stuff, you need to show us what you've attempted.

Comment: And pick a better title than that

Comment: i change the title mr. skaffman, now can u help me and write this program to me pls

Answer (score 3):

There are two main steps to solving a problems like this:

1. determine the algorithm and express it in pseudocode or a language such as C
2. implement (1) in assembler.

For step (1) you need to know that `n mod y`, where y is a power of 2, is equivalent to `n AND (y - 1)`.

Comment: ok man thank u. But i want to write the program of this equation in assembly language, how should i write it?                                                                  n=ax=0004,y=dx=02, then:                                                                 sub dx,01  ----> and ax,bx. Is this program right? if it is not can u write the right program plz,and thank u very much for answering me.peace

Comment: @sahar: Yes, that's correct. (Should be "and ax, dx" though.)